# Why ILSpy is adding variables on stack instead of Instructions?

Tags: ilspy

Why ILSpy is adding variables on stack instead of Instructions? I mean, when pushing or poping from/on stack it adds Ldloc and Stloc instructions. Can anyone explain why it has this behaviour? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a stack slot acts like a variable: it can be used multiple times (e.g. on both branches of an `if`), but the effect of the instruction only happens once, when the value is pushed on the stack.

A decompiler that uses a stack of instructions would effectively cause the side effects of the instruction to instead happen at the point where the value is popped from the stack. This would be a program reordering that could subtly change program behavior -> incorrect decompilation.

In principle, using a stack of instructions would be possible within basic blocks; but when there's control flow (either outgoing or incoming) or a `dup` instruction, the whole stack of instructions would have to be converted to a stack of variables.
Currently the ILSpy `ILReader` uses a single pass (as specified in the Ecma-335 spec), so it doesn't know about incoming control flow during the `ILReader` run, so it has to always use a stack of variables to be safe.

It turns out that this is not how the .NET framework reads IL bytecodes, and some obfuscators are exploiting the difference. So in the future, we may rewrite the `ILReader` to work more like the .NET bytecode importer, at which point we might move to the mixed stack of variables+stack of instructions model. [ILSpy issue #901](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/issues/901)